how to know what to use for default base constructor in erc721 smart contract?
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

    contract GarageSaleNFT is ERC721, Ownable {
        uint256 private _tokenIdCounter;
    
        // Define string constants
        string public constant TOKEN_NAME = "MyNFT";
        string public constant TOKEN_SYMBOL = "MYNFT";
        string public constant TOKEN_NOT_OWNED_BY_SENDER = "Token not owned by sender";
        string public constant CALLER_NOT_OWNER = "Ownable: caller is not the owner";
    
        constructor(address ownerAddress) ERC721(TOKEN_NAME, TOKEN_SYMBOL) {
            transferOwnership(ownerAddress);
        }
    
        function mint(address to) external onlyOwner {
            _tokenIdCounter++;
            _safeMint(to, _tokenIdCounter);
        }
    
        function burn(uint256 tokenId) external onlyOwner {
            _burn(tokenId);
        }
    
        function migrate(address from, address to, uint256[] memory tokenIds) external onlyOwner {
            for (uint256 i = 0; i < tokenIds.length; i++) {
                require(ownerOf(tokenIds[i]) == from, TOKEN_NOT_OWNED_BY_SENDER);
                _safeTransfer(from, to, tokenIds[i], "");
            }
        }
    
        // Modify the onlyOwner modifier to apply to all functions
        modifier onlyOwner() {
            require(_msgSender() == owner(), CALLER_NOT_OWNER);
            _;
        }
    
        // Override Ownable's _msgSender function to support contract calls
        function _msgSender() internal view virtual override returns (address sender) {
            return Ownable._msgSender();
        }
    
        // Override Ownable's _msgData function to support contract calls
        function _msgData() internal view virtual override returns (bytes calldata) {
            return Ownable._msgData();
        }
    }

i already tried a empty constructor with no params. what i thought would happen is i can connect my wallet through remix for the gas fees and i would not need to even give a ownerAddress but im not sure if i do or not ?
can you guys paste this into remix ..i got the following error :


This is not about the ERC721, it's related to Ownable. After OZ V5 the Ownable library takes a constructor argument, prior to that it is simply used to make the msg.sender owner.
Now it gives the flexibility to explicitly set the owner during construction. You need to update your constructor like this:
   constructor(address ownerAddress) ERC721(TOKEN_NAME, TOKEN_SYMBOL) Ownable(ownerAddress) {
        }

Additionally, why are you trying to rewrite the onlyOwner modifier, you can't override that nonvirtual modifier.

i will try your suggestions shortly. about the owner override i want to ensure for the smart contract only the owner can make changes. its for a ticketing system and there is no buying or selling afterwards. its a one time event so i for security i want to lock down any other calls so that only the owner can do it.

your correct, im not able to rewrite onlyOwner. its final method. so any idea how i can go about making sure only i as the owner can update the contract if my contract address got into the wrong hands ? can i just put "external onlyOwner" after every method i only want the owner to call ?

The thing you are trying to do is reason why the Ownable library exists. Yes, you can just use the onlyOwner modifier with the functions without overriding it, as it is by default made for this particular purpose.
